# GoogleAccountDataService appears to have been spoofed by: com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, android-source, google-account

Context: I'm trying to install Google Apps onto a ROM built from AOSP, running on a Nexus 5.

When I try to add a Google account to the device however, it gives me an error message saying: "There was a problem communicating with Google servers". From running logcat, I get the following messages:

```
V/GLSActivity( 2416): java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleAccountDataService appears to have been spoofed by: com.google.android.gms
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.dataservice.GoogleAccountDataServiceClient.c(Unknown Source)
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.dataservice.GoogleAccountDataServiceClient.a(Unknown Source)
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.dataservice.GoogleAccountDataServiceClient.signIn(Unknown Source)
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GLSHelper.blockingAddWithPassword(GLSHelper.java:281)
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivityTask$1.runInBackground(LoginActivityTask.java:147)
V/GLSActivity( 2416):   at com.google.android.gsf.login.CancelableCallbackThread.run(CancelableCallbackThread.java:37)
```

Has anyone else had this issue before? It seems to be some sort of permissions issue?

Note: I'm more curious as to what is the cause behind this security exception than how to fix it (though that would be appreciated too).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It might be easier to get help on this specific problem on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)